# How to click on the popup element in chrome using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

During test my automation code, I met a horrible web page.

When I click a element, the page present new browser window and alert.

After that, I can't do anything because the alert is invincible.

How can I go through this?

My environment is as following:

- Python 3.6.7
- Selenium 3.141.0

Please try this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.kebhana.com/foreign/index.do')

el = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="header"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[21]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[4]/a')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",el)
```

Then, you can see a new browser window with alert.

And I can't find any solution to dismiss that alert.

If you have some brilliant way to handle alert, please show me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic to switch to the new window and then accept the alert.

```
# this will switch to the new window
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
# now accept the alert
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

Comment: `switch_to.alert.accept()` is not working for this case. :(

Answer (score 0):

The element is a *Layer Message* and part of the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) and to locate and to click/dismiss the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#opbLayerMessage0_OK[href$='HanaBank']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='opbLayerMessage0_OK' and contains(@href, 'HanaBank')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Sorry for late comment, and what I want to handle is not the `"//a[@id='opbLayerMessage0_OK' and contains(@href, 'HanaBank')]"`, the browser alert on new window after `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",el)`